# How to see the list of objects in current file in Visual C++ 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, objectbrowser

Assume we have the huge Visual Studio solution and there are many files (tabs) opened. Does Visual Studio 2012 (Visual C++ particularly) have any View panel which will show the interactive list of objects from the current file when I switch to the corresponding tab? Or maybe there is an official extension which will help me? The standart Object Browser is not exactly what I want, because I'd like to see the *list of all objects from the current file and only them.*
Thanks!

Edit: I mean the list of all classes, structures, variables, methods etc., no matter declared or only defined in this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try Visual-Assist extension? It might be helpful.

http://www.wholetomato.com/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use **Object Browser**.

The Object Browser lets you select and examine the namespaces, classes, methods, and other programming symbols available for use in your project. You can open the Object Browser from the View menu, by clicking the Object Browser button on the main toolbar, or by typing `CTRL+ALT+J`. It will work for VS2005, VS2008, VS2010 and VS2012. Check out [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/exy1facf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#objectbrowsertoolbar) for more info.

---

**EDIT**: If you want to see a so-called `global tree view`. I only know this works for WPF projects. You can use the WPF Tree visualizer to explore the visual tree of a WPF object, and to view the WPF dependency properties for the objects that are contained in that tree. For more information about visual trees, see Trees in WPF. For more information about dependency properties, see Dependency Properties Overview. Check out [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409789%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, but it's not very convenient: the solution I'm working on has ~50 projects, ~4000 classes etc; so there is one gloval object tree for all of the symbols in this solution.